# Create a new Date() in JavaScript with my parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have the following code:

```
$(function () {
    var timestamp = 1443563590; //Tue, 29 Sep 2015 21:53:10 GMT
    var today2 = moment.unix(timestamp).tz('America/New_York').toString();

        alert(today2);
    //var dateinNewYork = new Date(what should I type here?);
    //alert(dateinNewYork.getHours());
});
```

and I want to create a new date based on what you can see above. In the future I will get the timestamp from the server, so that thanks to it I'll always keep the current time in new york on client's side, whether he has the current time set up in his computer or not. How can I create this date then?
http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/5/

Comment: All you need is `new Date(timestamp*1000)`: [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Guys, I don't want a date from current timestamp, I want a date with american timezone..

Comment: @randomuser3 Subtract 4 or 5 hours from timestamp then?

Comment: @Siguza but what about taking care about daylight savings time? Should I modify my code during that time then too?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood you completely, but this is my attempt to answer from what I understood:

```
$(function () {
    var timestamp = 1443563590; //Tue, 29 Sep 2015 21:53:10 GMT
    var today2 = moment.unix(timestamp).tz('America/New_York').toString();

    alert(today2);

    var dateinNewYork = new Date(today2);
    alert(dateinNewYork.getHours());
});
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work, because this alert `alert(dateinNewYork.getHours());` shows me the current hour and not the one in new york..

Comment: The native `Date` constructor normalizes date strings to UTC - `getHours` will return the local time.

Comment: I see... I understand better now... let me see what I can concoct

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) which you can use like this:

```
var newYork = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
```

Comment: I'm already using moment.js :) please check my code carefully :)